# Adding inputs from simple_form into array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, simple-form, actionmailer

I'm trying to use simple_form to gather one or multiple email address, then pass those email addresses as an array so that ActionMailer can send out invitation emails to those addresses. Unsure about how to get all the input fields into one array that is passed to the controller and mailer. Here is what I have so far.

Input form:

```
<div class="user-group-partial">
<%= simple_form_for :user_emails, :url => "/user_groups/sent_emails/", :method => :post do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <div class="form-inputs">
            <%= f.input :email, :maxlength => 25 %>
            <%= f.input :email, :maxlength => 25 %>
            <%= f.input :email, :maxlength => 25 %>
        <br>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <%= f.button :submit, :class => "btn btn-primary", :value => "Invite Bros" %>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
<br>
```

Controller Method:

```
def send_invite_to_members   
    token = current_user.user_group.token
    email = params[:user_emails][:email]
    UserGroupMailer.group_invitation_email(email, token).deliver
    redirect_to '/user_groups', :notice => "Your invitations have been sent"
end
```

ActionMailer Method:

```
def group_invitation_email(email_address, token)
    @token = token.to_s
    mail to: email_address, subject: "You've been invited!"
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Check out https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Comment: I think this is overkill for what I'm trying to accomplish. These email addresses aren't related to a model, they just need to be passed on, and have an email sent to each of them once, that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to solve this is to use a text field with a helper label that instructs the user to type email addresses separated by spaces or commas.

Then in your controller you can split them up and send out each email with something like:

```
def send_invite_to_members   
  token = current_user.user_group.token
  emails = params[:user_emails][:emails].split(",") # or split(" ") if you want them separated by a space
  emails.each do |e|
    UserGroupMailer.group_invitation_email(e, token).deliver
  end
  redirect_to '/user_groups', :notice => "Your invitations have been sent"
end
```